# Java: Check if a multiple of 100 lies between two doubles

Tags: java

I want to check if something between (including) two doubles is a multiple of one hundred.

With `if (double1 % 100 == 0)` I can check one double, but I want to check two doubles.

Example:

`double double1 = 398, double2 = 399.6;`
should return false but
`double double1 = 797.5, double2 = 801.2;`
should return true.

Comment: So, what's your question?  What you have posted so far sounds like you're asking somebody to write your program for you, which is generally not well received here.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this right, you want *x* such that [ *double1* <= x <= *double2* ], *x* % 100 == 0 ?

Comment: I don't know how to compare these two variables. I don't think that should be called asking for a whole program. This is part of a levelling system where I want to check if the experience a player has exceeds a multiple of 100, having the old amount of experience and the new amount of experience.

Comment: So, you're asking how to tell if the hundreds digit of two doubles is different?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, only that double1 mustn't be equal, so [ double1 < x <= double2 ],

Comment: So here's a hint:  the fact that they're doubles is a red herring.  You don't care if they're at 99.9.  So, you should only be looking at integers for your range.  You should convert them from a double to an int (this is straightforward with `Double#intValue`.

Comment: Now e.g. 99.9 will be 99 and 100.1 will be 100, but I still can't see how to check if a multiple of 100 lies between the two.

Comment: An idea I have would be to check how many times I can devide the two by 100. Is there an easier way or should I just do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then the following steps might just help:

- Ceil the smaller and floor the larger double number then cast both to integers
- user a for loop to check if any of the integers from the smallest to the largest is a multiple of 100.

Based on the assumption that the first number is always less than the second, an example code is shown below, this is not very efficient though.

```
static boolean isDivisibleby100(double double1, double double2) {
    int int1 = (int) Math.ceil(double1);
    int int2 = (int) Math.floor(double2);

    for (int i = int1; i <= int2; i++) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Come on, you don't need a loop for this, you can do it in O(1) with some additional work.

Comment: You are very right. That is exactly why i said myself that it was not efficient. however, the maximum the loop will go is 100.  Not too bad.

Comment: Well, the max number of iterations of the loop is not 100.

Comment: It is 100. After 100 iterations, you must see an integer divisible by 100 and then the function returns true which exits the loop. It is not possible to go 100 iterations and not see a multiple of 100. 1...100; -50...49; a multiple of 100 will always be there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that there will always be a different digit in the hundreds position (*and greater*), when the case is `true`

```
double1 = 398
          ^ //look at that digit - (and greater)
double2 = 399.6
          ^ //they are the same, return false!



double1 = 797.5
          ^ //look at that digit - (and greater)
double2 = 801.2
          ^ //they are not the same, return true!

double1 = 2300
          ^^ //look at that digit - (and greater)
double2 = 230
          ^ //they are not the same, return true!
```

---

You could easily compare them by turning them into an `int` value (*thus ignoring any decimal values*), and dividing by 100 (*chops off anything below the hundreds position since it is now an int*)

---

In the case where your values could also be negative, `-75` and `75` would both divide out to zero and be the same, resulting in returning `false`.

For this case, one simple way to check is to multiply the doubles and see if it is less than or equal to 0

```
double1 = -50;
double2 = 1;
//multiply, result is <= 0, return true

double1 = -5;
double2 = -2;
//multiply, result is > 0, return false

double1 = 1;
double2 = 3;
//multiply, result is > 0, return false

double1 = 0;
double2 = 3;
//multiply, result is <= 0, return true
```

Comment: Your tip is ingenious, but how do you account for numbers <  100?

Comment: @Makoto, take 50 and 150 as an example. 50 is also 050. the digits are still different. the only true special case is 0. See 50 and -50. For this, a special check if one number is + and the other is - should suffice.

Comment: @Hoten:  I understand the logic just fine, but I want to be sure that there's nothing else that's being missed here.

Comment: As it seems it does not work for example for 2300 and 230. EDIT: As @Hoten said

Comment: you would run into issues where `double1 > -100` and `double2 < 100`, nice catch - you may also have to compare the signs of the double.

Comment: @Baustein the method of comparison I suggested will actually compare that as `23 vs 2` - but I should clarify some wording

Comment: @Hoten I clarified wording - the way I suggested to do it would actually compare it as `11 vs 1`

Answer (score 0):

Given doubles d1 and d2, is there an integer x such that x is a multiple of 100 and in the range [d1, d2]?

1) If the difference between the two numbers is >= 100, return true.

2) If d1 / 100 (integer division) != d2 / 100, return true

3) If d1 * d2 <= 0, return true

4) If either d1 or d2 is a multiple of 100, return true

5) return false

Step 1 handles cases such as (100, 1100). Step 2 handles cases such as (250, 300). Step 3 handles cases such as (-5, 5), or (0, 10). Step 4 handles cases such as (100, 101).

```js
function test(d1, d2) {
  if (d2 - d1 >= 100) return true;
  if (((d1/100)|0) != ((d2/100)|0)) return true;
  if (d1*d2 <= 0) return true;
  if ((d1|0) % 100 == 0 || (d2|0) % 100 == 0) return true;
  return false;
}

var cases = [
             true, 100, 200, 
             true, 0, 1, 
             true, -5, 5, 
             true, 99, 101, 
             true, 10.2, 101.2, 
             true, -0.1, 1.1,
             true, 100, 100,
             true, 0, 0,
             false, 50, 99, 
             false, 101, 102, 
             false, 394.3, 399.9,
             false, 1, 1,
             false, 1001.2, 1001.4
            ];

for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i += 3) {
  if (test(cases[i + 1], cases[i + 2]) != cases[i]) {
      alert("fail! " + cases[i + 1] + " " + cases[i + 2]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other solutions suggested here are a bit too complex.
Here is how you can do it in O(1).

```
public class Test011 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(containsMultipleOf100(99.5, 101.2));
        System.out.println(containsMultipleOf100(101.1, 201.2));
        System.out.println(containsMultipleOf100(100.001, 199.992));
    }

    static boolean containsMultipleOf100(double double1, double double2) {
        long int1 = (long) Math.ceil(double1);
        long int2 = (long) Math.floor(double2);

        if ((int2 - (int1-1)) >= 100){
            return true;
        }else{
            return (int2 / 100) * 100 >= int1;
        }
    }
}
```